# why my php code does'nt work on wamp server

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code, but it doesn'nt seem to execute on my WAMP server. It just returns the .php pages as raw text. Am I missing some obvious syntax or configuration?.

```
    <?php
    $uname =$_POST["uname"];
    $email =$_POST["email"];
    $pw =$_POST["password"];
    $pw2 =$_POST["repassword"];
    $cno =$_POST["cnumber"];
    $add =$_POST["add"];

    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("rcj company",$con);

    mysql_query("INSRET INTO customer(username, email, password, cnumber, address)VALUES('".$uname."', '".$email."', '".$pw."', '".$pw2."', '".$cno."', '".$add."')");
    mysql_close($con);

    ?>
```

Comment: What URL are you trying to access it on?

Comment: Is your url starting with `http://localhost` or not ?? When you get it working , your query will fail as the keyword is `INSERT` and not `INSRET`

Comment: did you meane html form action url? no it is not.

Comment: Nope not that. The URL which is on your address bar.

Comment: http://localhost/final%20year%20project/registerHandler.php this the url on my address bar

Answer (score 1):

`Reinstall` your `Wamp server` and then check it,

And also fix the bugs what you did in your query,

For example change `INSRET` to `INSERT`.

Comment: Why did you write `Reinstall`? What code-like significance does that word have?

Comment: Because other reason for php pages getting returned as raw text is badly compiled/installed php.

Comment: Since in the question he mentioned `It just returns the .php pages as raw text`. Wamp server sometimes makes problems. If he reinstall's that will get ok.

Comment: @DineshBabu Which is more likely, a problem with a widely-used and heavily tested software, or PEBCAK?

Comment: Wampserver is more likely the problem its a known bug

Answer (score 0):

You must actually access it from the server, ie. with a URL like `http://localhost/test.php`, otherwise you're just asking the browser to get the file from your hard drive!

Also, `INSRET` isn't going to work, and of course obligatory xkcd reference:

[image: xkcd]

Sanitise your inputs before it is too late! — Or better still, use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), I actually just started using it yesterday - not because I'm incapable of writing valid MySQL queries the "raw" way, but because it's actually really tidy.

Also also, *always* enclose your table and column names in `` `backticks` ``! Otherwise you're relying on the same behaviour as what makes `$foo = bar;` a "valid" way to define a string, namely "if it's not a constant or other keyword, it must be [a string / an identifier]"

Comment: You should actually tell him to use _Prepared Statements_ .. which is a direct way instead of all those bobby tables thingy ;) **+1** anyway !

Comment: For the image he used for explanation -1

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol making fun ah..! :P

Comment: i installed again wamp server and corrected spelling mistake.but anything doesn't change.it returns again that error which i mention above

Comment: what is the reason for that?